# How to block all windows of swing application and display JDialog on top of them?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog, joptionpane

I have application which is write as JFrame. I have some dialog windows.

main_window[JFrame] -> edit_user[JDialog] -> change_pass[JDialog]

Hierarchy looks kind like this above. I also have process (Thread) which is monitoring internet connection.

What I would like to do is to display JDialog **on top of all open windows ( of my application )** when connection is down.  **I need to block my application windows as well.**

I don't want to use setAlwaysOnTop() as that will put i on top of all open applications.

Answer (score 7):

[Java Tutorials: How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html).

> **Modal dialog box** — A dialog box that blocks input to some other
>   top-level windows in the application, except for windows created with
>   the dialog box as their owner. The modal dialog box captures the
>   window focus until it is closed, usually in response to a button
>   press.

Comment: Where `JOptionPane.show*` is by far the easiest way to show such a dialog

Comment: I actually want to block top-level-window and windows created with the dialog box as their owner or dispose them any ideas?